# Pass parameters into TypeScript script and run it

Tags: typescript

So I'm new to `typescript`. I wanted to create very simple HelloWorld where I can pass parameter (here mentioned string) to script, but I'm unable to get it to work. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
let sentence: string = process.argv[1];

console.log(sentence);
```

But when I try to compile it (`tsc file.ts`) to produce `file.js` file to execute it with `node file.js "HelloWorld"` I get following error for process

`` error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`. ``
Even after I run command mentioned in Error msg. What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

Well in typescript, you need type definitions to support functions and props.
Do as its suggesting you to

```
npm i @types/node
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding a `tsconfig.json` file and run `tsc` from the same folder:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
        "types": ["node"],
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "files": ["file.ts"]
}
```

By default, `node_modules/@types` directories would be referenced:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html